# How to interactively run mount command from a (Ruby) script?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, interactive, mount

I am trying to write a Ruby script that runs the `mount` command *interactively* behind the scenes. The problem is, if I redirect input and output of the mount command to pipes, it doesn't work. Somehow, mount seems to realise that it's not talking directly to stdin/stdout and falls over. Either that, or it's a more wide-ranging problem that would affect all interactive commands; I don't know.

I want to be able to parse the output of `mount`, line by line, and shove answers into its input pipe when it asks questions. This shouldn't be an unreasonable expectation. Can someone help, please?

Examples:

```
def read_until(pipe, stop_at, timeoutsec = 10, verbose = false)
    lines = []; line = ""
    while result = IO.select([pipe], nil, nil, timeoutsec)
        next if result.empty?
        begin
            c = pipe.read(1) rescue c = nil
        end
        break if c.nil?

        line << c
        break if line =~ stop_at

        # Start a new line?
        if line[-1] == ?\n
            puts line if verbose
            lines << line.strip
            line = ""
        end
    end
    return lines, line.match(stop_at)
end
cmd = "mount.ecryptfs -f /tmp/1 /tmp/2"
status = Open3::popen2e(cmd) { |i,o,t|
    o.fcntl(3, 4)   # Set non-blocking (this doesn't make any difference)
    i.fcntl(3, 4)   # Set non-blocking (this doesn't make any difference)
    puts read_until(o, /some pattern/, 1, true)   # Outputs [[], nil]
}
```

I've also tried `spawn`:

```
a, b = IO.pipe
c, d = IO.pipe
pid = spawn(cmd, :in=>a, :out=>d)
puts read_until(c, /some pattern/, 1, true)   # Outputs [[], nil]
```

I've tried `subprocess`, `pty` and a host of other solutions - basically, if it's on Google, I've tried it. It seems that mount just *knows* if I'm not passing it a real shell, and deliberately blocks. See:

```
pid = spawn(cmd, :in=>STDIN, :out=>STDOUT)             # Works
pid = spawn(cmd, :in=>somepipe, :out=>STDOUT)          # Blocks after first line of output, for no reason whatsoever. It's not expecting any input at this point.
```

I even tried spawning a real shell (e.g. bash) and sending the mount command to it via an input pipe. Same problem.

*Please ignore any obvious errors in the above: I have tried several solutions tonight, so the actual code has been rewritten many times. I wrote the above from memory.*

What I want is the following:

- Run mount command with arguments, getting pipes for its input and output streams
- Wait for first specific question on output pipe
- Answer specific question by writing to input pipe
- Wait for second specific question on output pipe
- *...etc...*

And so on.

Comment: I'm not aware of `mount` being interactive.  But if your system provides an interactive version of `mount`, then this could well test whether its stdin/stdout are ttys (and thus probably interactive) and if not behave differently.  In this case all you can do is try to replace your interactive usage with a command-line usage which is not interactive (I'd prefer that anyway), or you could bite the sour apple and create a tty to communicate through with the interactive `mount` command.

Comment: @Alfe: Um....how would I create a tty? I'm not even sure what a tty is! And yes, mount.ecryptfs is interactive. Non-interactive methods are possible, but there is no way to validate the passphrase non-interactively.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question in the future, check out `PTY.spawn` and `IO.select`. Thanks to Alfe for the hint.

Comment: Sorry for not showing up again quicker to give more hints (but I must admit that I'm not familiar with the Ruby libraries anyway, so I probably wouldn't be too much help), congratulations on solving it yourself and thanks for sharing the solution (or at least a second hint on it).

Comment: Two more things came to mind when reading your comment here:  ① Your question was *very* special, so it is quite likely that not many readers here are in the least familiar with any way of solving it (so no hard feelings about unhelpful users here; probably just nobody had an idea).  ② In case you solved your problem yourself, it is possible in StackOverflow to give an answer yourself *and accept it*.  This way other people having a similar problem can find a solution here and even upvote your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) useful. It opens a subshell, so if you are ok w/ the user just interacting with `mount` directly this will make everything much easier.